# De quel complément s'agit il ? COD ,COI ?

Tags: grammaire

> Jouer au tennis.

Répond à la question jouer quoi, à quoi ~ cod ou coi

Answer (score 3):

C'est un complément d'objet indirect (*jouer **à quoi*** ?) Note : **au** ="**à** **le**"

Quelques exemples de COD avec jouer (*jouer **quoi***):

> *Elle joue sa carrière.*
> *Il joue la comédie.*
> *J'ai joué dix euros.*
> *Il n'a pas joué la balle.*

Comment: Peut-être ça vaut le coup de rappeler que *à + le = au*.

Comment: Peut-être vaut-il la peine de se rappeler que...
(Peut-être ça vaut) n'étant pas une formulation correcte sauf votre respect.

Comment: @tatactic 1. Il faut préciser à qui est adressé un commentaire avec @ suivi du pseudo. 2. *Peut-être ça vaut le coup* n'est pas une formulation académique, c'est sûr, mais c'est parfaitement compréhensible et couramment employé dans un registre relâché, plus souvent à l'oral, j'en conviens.

Comment: @jilliagre J'en prend bonne note.
Le but était juste d'améliorer la formulation à l'écrit, sans arrière pensée aucune.
Bien à vous.